# 'Module' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and django and having trouble doing a math function in my model.py file.

```
class Orders(models.Model):
  ...
  total = models.DecimalField(
                              max_digits = 6,
                              decimal_places = 2,
                              null = True,
                              blank = True,
                              )
  ...  


  def shipping(self):
      t = self.total
      ship_rate = 0.12
      return(t*ship_rate)
```

When I call it in a python shell

```
dat = Orders.object.get(pk=12)
dat.shipping()
```

Then I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\xx\xx\models.py", line 613, in shipping  
ship_rate = 0.12  
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saying that the error happens on the line `ship_rate = 0.12`?

Comment: yes, that is the line through the error

Comment: Hm... that's *very* odd. Could you show the full stack trace?

Comment: I also tried changing to ship_rate = decimal(0.12), same error.  (and I did import decimal)

Comment: Please don't use `try` as a name for a variable.

Comment: 'try' is a python keyword - you should get a syntax error if you use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is because you used

```
ship_rate = decimal(0.12)
```

This should be

```
ship_rate = decimal.Decimal(0.12)
```

`decimal` is the name of the module.  You can't call a module, that's what the error message says.  The reason for the strange traceback you got is that the module source and the code in memory got out of sync.  When the traceback is created, the current version of the file is used, which might not be the version of the code that is actually running.  Always reload your webserver to ensure it is using the most recent version of your code.

Comment: @David__: Then the old code is still running.  What webserver are you using?  Try to make some changes in the same file that are guaranteed to show up in the response to be able to verify that you are really using the most recent version of the code.

Comment: I just noticed you ran this from the Python shell.  In this case: restart Python, not the webserver.  Python does not reload modules once they are imported unless you explicitly use `reload()`.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I had restarted the python code and had the same problem.  But stumped upon using your decimal.Decimal(0.12), but making the number in quotes.  So what worked was the: ship_rate = decimal.Decimal('0.12')

Comment: @David__: Godd that it's working now.  In Python versions up to 2.6 you could not directly convert a `float` to a `Decimal`. This would never give you the error message "'module' object is not callable" tough, but rather "Cannot convert float to Decimal.  First convert the float to a string".  The only way a traceback like the one in your question can arise is if running code and source code on disk get out of sync.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typo: The manager is called `objects`.

Comment: That isn't what is causing the error.  All the other queries on the model work fine, except for the ones using number in the math.

Comment: Try to create an example that can be reproduced by everyone around here and please provide correct code in the example. It's impossible to help you solve the problem when the example you're giving wouldn't even reach the line that is causing the error. Also: a little more stacktrace would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the class `order = orders()` then you can call `order.shipping()`

python class convention is also capital Class names `Order` and django conventions is singular name so it could be `Order` instead of `orders`